# Inserting or Updating bulk records from oracle database to Mysql database using java

Tags: java, mysql, oracle

I have 200 000 data in oracle db and 300 000 data in Mysql db with same columns. I want to Insert or update mysql dp comparing to data in oracle db.

I am  trying with JDBC,Spring boot jpa but I have to loop through records in both db for checking if particular data is already present or any changes in existing data compared to data in oracle db, which is very time consuming as well as unprofessional.

Is there any solution or any comparison technique which can reduce time and also better performance?

Comment: I'm quite sure you'll get a lot of results in google with bulk load + the name of the db you want to load into. So... did you tryi anything?

Comment: of course I have..the scenario is not just bulk load into db,I have to compare data in two databases and then insert  or update based on result of compare.I am searching for efficient way to compare and insert using jdbc or any other way

Comment: Use ORDER BY in your SQL queries that retrieve data from MySQL and Oracle.

Comment: If a bulk load is too slow, you need to specify actual requirements, rather than "efficient". I don't see any point in coding your own comparison logic in java or anywhere outside the database unless you have some really special requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Which columns of your MySql table identify the rows well enough to decide whether the Oracle table contains a duplicate row?

You almost certainly have enough RAM to read those columns from all the rows in your MySql table into a HashSet collection.

Then read the rows from the Oracle table one by one, and look them up in your HashSet (that's fast). If a row is not in the HashSet insert it into MySql. If it does match, do whatever your application requires.

Or, look up how to use MySql's `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` query pattern. If your indexes are correct, that too can be fast.